# color change on button click

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uicolor

In my signature view, I want to give option to change the color on Ibaction. For example, if the user clicks the button red, the drawing color should be red, like that, I tried with the tutorial http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-beginner-tutorials/digital-signature-application-in-iphone/, Here the coloring code

```
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

My doubt is how to give this as seperate on button method, and perform the color on clicking?

Comment: Check if this helps in someway https://github.com/yusenhan/Smooth-Line-View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi just make values as variables and

if you are writing this code inside `drawrect method`

you can update by `[self setNeedsDisplay];`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alpha);
}

-(IBAction)updateColor{

   redValue = red color code;
   greenValue = green color code;
   blueValue = blue color code;
  alphaValue = alpha value;

   [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply write this code on red button click

```
       [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```